# Does "should not have (past participle)" have the same meaning as "should have not to (verb)"?

Tags: meaning

Are they the same meaning? Or grammatically it's right?
I used grammar check online but it said both are correct.

For example,

> You should not have **believed** him.
> You should have not **to believe** him.

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 1):

'You should have not to believe him' is ungrammatical. The example is better adjusted also.

> 'You should not have worked so late.' means 'You ought to have
>   finished working earlier.' [usually, a friendly upbraiding]

but

> 'You should not have to work so late.' means 'You are being compelled 
>   / obliged to work beyond a reasonable time.' [usually, a comment that
>   too much is being expected of you, though it could again be friendly upbraiding, implying that you are asking too much *of yourself*]

Answer (score 0):

The correct structure of this sentence must be:

Subject + should + not + verb

[For this case] Subject + should + not + have + past participle

Therefore, the correct sentence is **You should not have believed him**.

Reference: https://blog.abaenglish.com/negative-sentences-with-must-and-should/